How can I run a script/cmd on "explicit" save in vscode?
I have tried extenstions like Run On Save with this configuration:
    "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": "\\.(js|ts|jsx|tsx)$",
                "cmd": "bunx @biomejs/biome lint ${file} --write --unsafe"
            }
        ]
    },

The issue here is that I use auto save and this script runs everytime the file autosaves which I don't want to happen. It should only run when I explicitly save the file by hitting ctrl+s.


It should only run when I explicitly save the file by hitting ctrl+s

If you only care about what happens when you use the keybinding (and not when the command palette or menus are used), then that's easy. Just rebind the keybinding.
{
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": { "text": "echo hi\u000D" }, // expects a terminal to be open already. you can add a terminal view focus command if you want.
        },
    ]},
},

If you want something for macOS and other platforms, duplicate the definition, and give the one with "key": "cmd+s" a "when": "isMac", and the other a "when": "!isMac".
